# The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform mediatoolkit

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this function to get the duration of an mp3 file using [mediaToolKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaToolkit/).

but when execute `engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);` I have an exception that is :

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'

```
private string getDuration()
        {
            string orginalFilePath = LocalMediaPath;
            if (File.Exists(orginalFilePath))
            {
                var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = orginalFilePath };
                using (var engine = new Engine())
                {
                    engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);
                    return inputFile.Metadata.Duration.TotalSeconds.ToString();
                }
            }
            else
                return "-1";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found the source code.](https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolkit#get-started)

**It works well!**

[image]

Snippet：

```
using MediaToolkit;
using MediaToolkit.Model;
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputFile = new MediaFile { Filename = @"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\music\123.mp3" };
            using (var engine = new Engine())
            {
                engine.GetMetadata(inputFile);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(inputFile.Metadata.Duration);
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Change your file, it is likely that your file is not supported.**

Comment: the problem was in mp3 file itself, thank you and sorry for long time to response